# How to manage probabilities in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, probability

I have 2 2D arrays that store data for a fractal. My first array has 3 rows and the last value of each row is the probability.

Row 1 has 0.33 probability,
Row 2 has 0.33 probability, and
Row 3 has 0.34 probability

Right now what I am doing is I generate a random double from 0-1.
and I use if statements to determine which row I should be using.

here are my arrays:

```
    static double[][] SierpGasketMatrix = { { 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.33 }, //row 1
                                            { 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.33 }, //row 2
                                            { 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.43, 0.25, 0.34 } }; //row 3

    static double[][] BarnsleyFernMatrix = { { 0, 0, 0, 0.16, 0, 0, 0.01 }, //row 1
                                             { 0.85, 0.04, -0.04, 0.85, 0, 1.6, 0.85 }, //row 2 
                                             { 0.2, -0.26, 0.23, 0.22, 0, 1.6, 0.07 }, //row 3
                                             { -0.15, 0.28, 0.26, 0.24, 0, 0.44, 0.07 } }; //row 4
```

here is the code to determine which row to use:

```
            double randNum = Math.random();
            int row = -1;

            if (randNum < 0.33)
                row = 0;
            else if (randNum < 0.66)
                row = 1;
            else if (randNum < 1.00)
                row = 2;
```

I  feel as if there should be a better way to do this. Also, my second array has 4 rows and different probabilities and I would like to use the same method for that array.

Comment: Do you specifically want 0.33, 0.33 and 0.34, or if they were closer to 1/3 would that be better?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a general solution, just iterate the array until you reach the threshold. The result is not really any slower than what you're doing.

```
static double[] getRandomRow(double[][] data) {
    double randNum = Math.random();
    double threshold = 0.0;
    for (double[] row : data) {
        threshold += row[row.length - 1]; // probability = last value of row
        if (threshold > randNum)
            return row;
    }
    // We should never get here, but float math is imprecise, so just return last row.
    // Could also be that input probabilities don't add to 1, so handle that if necessary.
    return data[data.length - 1];
}
```

Comment: @kaya3 Question explicitly says *"the last value of each row is the probability"*.

Comment: Should `>` be `>=`?

Comment: @cybersam The difference between `>` and `>=` is basically irrelevant for doubles, but theoretically `>` is correct; consider if the first probability is 0, and the number generated is exactly 0, then `>=` would select the first row (incorrectly, since a probability of 0 should be impossible).

Comment: @cybersam No. Flip the condition to `if (randNum < threshold)` and it reads the same as the question code. On last iteration, `threshold` should be `1.0` (barring any cumulative rounding errors), and since [`Math.random() < 1.0`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--), so is `randNum`, so the condition is valid.